# Спуск в низ страницы в selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Надо сделать скриншот страницы, но до этого должен спуститься вниз. Использую клавишу 'end', но происходит ошибка.
Это не получается: `driver[i].send_keys(Keys.END)`

Пишет: `'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`[image: class: pull-right]

Comment: Этому вопросу почти 3 года))) но))) driver.send_keys()........ "учу python - нажимаю на все кнопки")))) иначе это не назовёшь)))

Comment: Это как заводить автомобиль пожарным гидрантом)))

Comment: Команда из контекста одного места, применяется к объекту в другом месте))))

Comment: Ты сделал мой день) Спасибо)))))

Comment: Надеюсь у тебя всё отлично, и твой скилл в питоне сейчас во много раз превосходит тот, который был у тебя 3 года назад))))) Удачи тебе))

Answer (score 2):

Найдите какой-нибудь элемент на форме и у него вызывайте [send_keys](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys)

Comment: Я понял, но не может найти элемент. Ищу надпись. Пишет `no such element`.

Comment: Приложите к вопросу html текст того элемента и код поиска

Comment: Всё поискал другое решение. Странно, но это не работает в редакторе, но спокойно работает через консоль